# 1D Heat Induction Equation in Python

Tags: python, equation, differential-equations

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to solve the analytical solution of the head induction equation in Python. I wrote a code but it doesn't work as I want and I cannot fix it.

Here you can find the given analytical solution :
[image: Analytical Equation]

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("1D heat equation solver for a wall (Analytical Solution)")

wall_thickness = 31  # Thickness of the wall in centimeters
L = wall_thickness  # Length of the wall
max_time = 1800  # Total simulation time in seconds
delta_x = 0.05
delta_t = 0.01
D = 93 #Diffusivity coeficient

# Define the spatial grid
x = np.arange(0, L + delta_x, delta_x)

# Initialize solution: the grid of u(x, t)
u = np.empty((max_time, len(x)))

# Set the boundary conditions
u_sur = 149  # Surrounding temperature
u_in = 38.0  # Initial temperature inside the wall

# Set the initial condition
u[0] = u_in

Tbase = u_sur + 2 * (u_in - u_sur)
def analytical_solution(x, t):
    T = np.zeros_like(x)
    for m in range(1, 100):  # Sum from m=1 to a large number (e.g., 100)
        T += np.exp(-D*((m * np.pi) / L)**2*t) * ((1 - (-1) ** m) / (m * np.pi)) * np.sin((m * np.pi * x) / L)
    return Tbase + T

# Calculate the analytical solution for each time step
for k in range(1, max_time):
    t = k * delta_t
    u[k] = analytical_solution(x, t)
    #print(f"Valeurs de la sol analytique {u[k]}.\n")

# Plot the temperature profiles at specific time points
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
time_points = [0, 360, 720, 1080, 1440, 1800]
for t in time_points:
    k = int(t / delta_t)
    if k < max_time:
        plt.plot(x, u[k], label=f"t = {t} seconds")

plt.title("Temperature Profiles (Analytical Solution) at Specific Time Points")
plt.xlabel("x (thickness)")
plt.ylabel("Temperature")
plt.ylim(0,150)
plt.xlim(0, L)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print("Done!")
```

Here are the results that I obtained:
[image: Plot]

As you can see the results are incoherent, the curve drawn in red are what I expected...

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: In the formula, the `Σ ...` term is multiplied by `2(T_in - T_sur)`. But your code doesn't apply that multiplication: it is doing something more like `T_sur + 2(T_in - T_sur) + Σ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is heat *conduction*, not heat *induction*.

You have several problems. Firstly, you seem to be confusing the number of steps (k) with the time (t).

Secondly, as already pointed out by @slothrop in a comment, you have an error in combining your sum with the initial and side boundary conditions.

Thirdly, look at the expression (1 - (-1) ** m). This is 2 if m is odd and 0 if m is even - so you can massively simplify your sum by only considering odd m and setting this term to 2.

Fourthly, a physical issue - the distance diffused in a give time is of order sqrt( diffusivity * time ) and you have a diffusivity of 93 units and have to diffuse roughly half the width of the wall. I suggest that you use a smaller timestep if those "time" (actual index) points are what you say they are.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("1D heat equation solver for a wall (Analytical Solution)")

wall_thickness = 31.0        # Thickness of the wall in centimeters
L = wall_thickness           # Length of the wall
max_step = 1800              # Number of timesteps
delta_x = 0.05
delta_t = 0.001
D = 93                       # Diffusivity coeficient

# Define the spatial grid
x = np.arange(0, L + delta_x, delta_x )

# Initialize solution: the grid of u(x, t)
u = np.empty( ( 1 + max_step, len( x ) ) )

# Set the boundary conditions
u_sur = 149                  # Surrounding temperature
u_in = 38.0                  # Initial temperature inside the wall

# Set the initial condition
u[0] = u_in

def analytical_solution(x, t):
    T = np.zeros_like(x)
    for m in range( 1, 100, 2 ):       #  Sum from m=1 to a large number (e.g., 100)
        T += np.exp( - D * ( m * np.pi / L ) ** 2 * t ) * 2.0 / ( m * np.pi ) * np.sin( m * np.pi * x / L )
    return u_sur + 2 * ( u_in - u_sur ) * T

# Calculate the analytical solution for each time step
for k in range( 1, 1 + max_step ):
    t = k * delta_t
    u[k] = analytical_solution( x, t )
    #print(f"Valeurs de la sol analytique {u[k]}.\n")

# Plot the temperature profiles at specific time points
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
time_points = [ 0, 360, 720, 1080, 1440, 1800 ]
for k in time_points:
    if k <= max_step:
        plt.plot(x, u[k], label=f"t = { k * delta_t } seconds")

plt.title("Temperature Profiles (Analytical Solution) at Specific Time Points")
plt.xlabel("x (thickness)")
plt.ylabel("Temperature")
plt.ylim(0,150)
plt.xlim(0, L)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print("Done!")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and these nice explanations!